# How to show that $f(x) = 5x^{5}-8x^{4}+6x^{3}-4x^{2}+7x+9$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Rational Roots Theorem cannot be used since $\pm \frac{9,3,1}{5,1}$ are not zeroes of $f(x)$.

Eisentein's criterion cannot be used since the non-leading coefficients have no common factors.

For mod $p$ test, I tried $p=2$, but $\overline{f}(x) = x^{5} + x +1 = (x^{2}+x+1)(x^{3}+x^{2}+1)$.

For $p=3$, $\overline{f}(x)$ has a factor of $x$. $p=5$ is not possible since $deg \overline{f}=4 \neq 5 = deg f$.

I tried $p=7$ but got a linear factor.

Should I keep on looking for primes that could satisfy the mod p test or are there more efficient ways to show the desired conclusion?

Comment: What you could try is to look at the substitution $X \to X+1$ or maybe $X \to X-1$. Calculate the polynomials that you get using those substitutions. If you are lucky you can proof (probably with Eisenstein) that one of them is irreducible. If that is the case you know that your original polynomial is irreducible. (I have not tried it in this case, so it might not work. But usually that would be something I would consider if I have to show that a polynomial is irreducible and the basic strategies do not work).

Comment: @offline I tried this, also with $x\mapsto x+a$ for other values of $a$, but it didn't work so far. I think, solving equations modulo $13$ is probably saver. It will definitely work.

Comment: @DietrichBurde In this case, yes.

Comment: If the polynomial was reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, then it means it's solvable, but here the Galois group is the Symmetric group of $5$ objects,

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua It is much more difficult to compute the Galois group here than to solve the six equations over $\Bbb F_{13}$. How did you compute that it must be $S_5$?

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial is indeed irreducible over $\Bbb F_{13}$, and
$5$ is a unit in this field. We have
$$
f=5(x^5 + x^4 + 9x^3 + 7x^2 + 4x + 7).
$$

Comment: Which of the three methods I mentioned did you use?

Comment: As you said, I tried with $p=13$. Actually, $p=7,11$ also don't work.

Comment: How did you determine that $f=5(x^5 + x^4 + 9x^3 + 7x^2 + 4x + 7)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_{13}$?

Comment: Just by writing it as a product $5g(x)h(x)$ with $g$ of degree $3$ and $h$ of degree $2$ and comparing coefficients, over the finite field $\Bbb F_{13}$. This gives easy equations, with only a few possible values, and we see a contradiction. And, of course, it has no root in $\Bbb F_{13}$.

Comment: Alternatively, you compute the $\gcd$ of your polynomial and $x^{13^2}-x$ over $\Bbb F_{13}$. The result being $1$, we know that the polynomial has no root in $\Bbb F_{13^2}$. The advantage of this method is that it is algorithmic and hence can be done easily with a computer.

Comment: @WhatsUp Yes, exactly. One could also apply directly the [Berlekamp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm) to see whether or not $f$ is irreducible over a finite field.

Comment: The said algorithm was not yet discussed (or probably won't be discussed) in our class unfortunately

Comment: Therefore I used an elementary approach - easy equations over a finite field. If finite fields were not yet discussed, you can imagine integer coefficients modulo $p=13$, and solve the equations this way.

Comment: can you elaborate on how you have constructed the equations?

Comment: As ususal. Write $h(x)=x^2+ax+b$ and $g(x)=x^3+cx^2+dx+e$ and multiply out $5g(x)h(x)$. Compare this degree $5$ polynomial with your given $f(x)$. All coefficients must be equal, so we get $6$ equations in the variables $a,b,c,d,e$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, the equation there is a degree $10$...... There are a number of resolvent with would also tell us this

Comment: " so we get $6$ equations in the variables $a,b,c,d,e$ ", okay I mean the $6$ equations when combined from a $10$ degree

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua It seems you didn't write down the equations. They are easy to solve over the integers (modulo $p$).

Comment: are the equations $a+c=1, b+ac+d=9,bc+ad+e=7,bd+ae=4,be=7$?

Comment: I used the original $f$ of yours, and then I obtain also $5$ equations $5a+5c=-8=5,\cdots ,be=7$ etc. So yes, it looks good.